# Is there a way to test a program's hardware requirements without just using it on a bunch of different computers?

Tags: hardware, testing, compatibility

Is there a program out there or some other thing that will run some kind of virtualization for me or something, to test the hardware minimums for a program I write? Something I can do locally without install testing on, say, a 33 mhz 64kb ram IBM or something

Comment: (ghz - target lower ghz)/100 = instances of RealPlayer to open

Answer (score 0):

[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) is the standard, but Microsoft's [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv.aspx) may also do the trick (although I'm not sure how lousy a piece of hardware it can emulate).

The other nice thing is you can create a snapshot of a virgin machine right after an OS install and then roll back after testing your installation.

Comment: VMware and Hyper-V still use the underlying hardware on your machine (for example, you can't run a 64-bit virtual machine on 32-bit hardware).  I think what Matt is after is more of a static analysis type of tool that will work regradless of the hardware the tool is run on; I don't know of anything like that.